# Stability question (finite difference): dealing with corner nodes

Tags: pde, finite-difference, stability

Consider one initial boundary value problem for sphere.
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=\operatorname{div}A\nabla u +f$$
Here is explicit numerical scheme (we consider that it is stable):

$$\frac{u^{n+1}_{i,j,k}-u^{n}_{i,j,k}}{\Delta t}=A_{i,j,k}{\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}}_{i,j,k,+/-}^{n}+B_{i,j,k}{\frac{\partial u}{\partial \varphi}}_{i,j,k,+/-}^{n}+C_{i,j,k}{\frac{\partial u}{\partial \psi}}_{i,j,k,+/-}^{n}+
R_{i,j,k}{\frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial r^2}}_{i,j,k}^{n}+\Phi_{i,j,k}{\frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial \varphi^2}}_{i,j,k}^{n}+\Psi_{i,j,k}{\frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial \psi^2}}_{i,j,k}^{n}+f^{n}_{i,j,k} ;$$
$u(r,\varphi,\psi,t=0)=u_{0}(r,\varphi,\psi)$;$u(r=r_{0},\varphi,\psi,t)=0;$

Under $+/-$ for operator it is understood that for operator was used upwind scheme; the operators are standart.
It is clear that such scheme works for all domain, except points on $r=r_{0}$(actually, we don't need to compute values here, because they are known because of boundary condition) and for point $r=0$ in the center of the ball.

Consider the following method for evaluating $u^{n+1}$ in the center of the ball: we use the definition of divergence

$$\operatorname{div}(A(x,y,z))=\lim\limits_{R\to 0}\frac {\oint_{B_{R}(x,y,z)}{(A,n)ds}}{V_{R}}, $$
therefore,we can write

$$\frac{u^{n+1}_{1,j,k}-u^{n}_{1,j,k}}{\Delta t}=\frac {\oint_{B_{r_2}}{(A\nabla u,\overline{n})ds}}{V_{r_2}} +\overline{f}^{n}_{1,j,k} ,$$
where $B_{r_2}$ -- a ball of radius equal to the value of unit step for $r$, $\overline{f}$ -- mean value of $f$ on the surface of $B_{r_2}$.

Question: will this method be stable for the center of the point?
If not, what stable method of computing the value in the center of ball you can offer?